# Displaying the administrator view in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, frameworks

I have a small problem displaying the admin view. I searched, but I didn't find a good solution. I have a meeting table that stores the IDs of two different users and displays records depending on who is logged in.

I assign to the variable `Auth::user()->id` then call

```
$variable = MeetingModel::where('user_id, $variable)->orWhere('other_user,$variable)->get();
```

In this case, records assigned to specific logged in users are displayed. I would like the administrator to view all records. In addition, I have to refer to the user model and their type (administrator) in my query.

Comment: `where('user_id, $variable)` _and_ `orWhere('other_user,$variable)` are missing a closing `'`. What is "_the admin view_"? See [the documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views) on how to show views

Comment: What is identification flag or column in table to check normal user and administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
$id= Auth::user()->id;
$type = Auth::user()->type;

 if ($type == 'admin') {
     $variable= MeetingModel::all();
 } else {
    $variable= MeetingModel::where('user',$id)->orWhere('other_user',$id)->get();
}
```

Here you have to check `type` of logged in `user` if `type` column has `admin` value then it will fetch all data else only specific data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use when method's callback to dynamically load the records based on the user type. Something like this:

```
$notAdmin = (auth()->user()->type == "administrator") ? false : true;
$variable = MeetingModel::when($notAdmin, function($query){
                $query->where('user_id', auth()->id())->orWhere('other_user', auth()->id())
            })->get();
```